# Data are not visible after redraw the chart

Tags: highcharts

My [modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/dD3tv/) is basing on [Dynamically updated data example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update). My example has button which changes title (*it works*) and zoom type (*from x to y, also work*s).

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        chartOptions.chart.zoomType = 'y';
        chartOptions.title.text = 'Some New Title';
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', chartOptions);
});
```

The issue is that neither new nor old data are visible after click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts modify configuration object, so you need to use `$.extend()` to keep object in the same figure.

http://jsfiddle.net/dD3tv/4/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', $.extend({}, chartOptions));
```

I advice to destroy() first chart and then create new.